# I tried to visit vtable of a C++ polymorphic class, but failed with core dump, why?

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, virtual, vtable

I wish to use a small program to detect the feature of vtable. I know for most popular compilers, they'll generate objects with leading size_t of its head to be a pointer to vtable. So I tried to convert this pointer and use it for a direct function call.

```
typedef void (*pf)();
struct C
{
     virtual void f(){
       printf("weird\n");
     }
};
int main()
{
     C c1;
     C* p=&c1;
     pf* pvtable=(pf*)p;
     pf func1=pvtable[0];
     (*func1)();
     return 0;
}
```

I wish that (*func1)() will print out "weird". But the actural result was core dump.

Where did I get wrong in my program?
Thanks.

Comment: I think the bit you got wrong was relying on undocumented or implementation-specific behaviour :-)

Comment: are you sure the behaviour you're supposing is the proper one? And you call an instance method without the object. That cannot work.

Comment: Don't you want to use pointer on method instead ?

Comment: Firstly, don't use this in production code unless it's really required and you know what you're doing (and comment the reason). Secondly, a virtual member function has an implicit "this" parameter that you might want to pass in your example even if you're not using it.

Comment: Techniques described [here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

You have a mistake here:

```
pf* pvtable=(pf*)p;
```

You are casting the pointer to object `C` to a pointer to vtable. Therefore you are interpreting the content of the `C` object as a vtable. Instead you need to go one indirection further; cast the pointer to `C` to a pointer-to-pointer to vtable and dereference it:

```
pf* pvtable=*(pf**)p;
```

This way you will follow the pointer stored at the beginning of `C` object to the actual vtable.

---

**My original answer that is rewriten more**:

```
#include <iostream>

struct C
{
    virtual void f()
    {
        std::cout << "weird" << std::endl;
    }
};

typedef void** C_vtable;
typedef void (C_f)(C* thiz);

int main()
{
    // Create the object on stack
    C c1;

    // Reinterpret its address to an address of a virtual table and dereference it.
    C_vtable vtable = *reinterpret_cast<C_vtable*>(&c1);

    // Pick the first pointer from the virtual table and reinterpret it as our function
    C_f *func1 = reinterpret_cast<C_f*>(vtable[0]);

    // Call it
    (*func1)(&c1);

    return 0;
}
```

This will work at least with gcc and clang on Linux, possible with other compilers too. But it is implementation dependent!

Comment: Why does the original code not work? I don't think it's really "educational" if you say "throw away your code; use my code instead".

Comment: That's not what I meant by "educational", I meant *use it only for learning*. But you are right, I'll extend my answer.